# How to Hg Shelve Added files uncommitted yet

Tags: mercurial, shelving

I am using Mercurial [Shelve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension) to shelve changes from command line. It works nice except when the changes that i like to shelve contain new added files(a) in working directory. Basically, it shelves everything except the new added files. I checked this by looking at the .hg/shelve stored changes.

How to shelve new added files (a status)?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to shelve untracked files, because subsequent HG operations will not affect them.

Answer (score 13):

This response is overdue, but you can use the following command to shelve all files (track / untrack) :

```
hg shelve -A
```

or

```
hg shelve --addremove
```

About this command, documentation says :

> mark new/missing files as added/removed before shelving

You must pay attention by using this feature because after unshelving, your old untracked files are track.
These file are already to be commited in the last commit if no files are specified in hg commit command. You should use hg forget if you want untracked them again.

Comment: Note that adding does not commit them!

Comment: Yes, after hg shelve -A untracked files are tracked but not commited. They are already to be commited in the last commit if no files are specified in hg commit command. I complete my answer to be more specific. Thanks for comment :)

Comment: Thanks :) ... It's obvious, but normally I add files as part of the commit, so this point had kind of passed me by :S

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are talking about currently untracked files? You need to add the first.

So just do `hg add` for your new files and then `hg shelve` will also shelve them.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Tom. I am using Mac, so it didn't really worked. What did work was another mercurial extension 'hgattic' about which you can read more in my blog

http://margotskapacs.com/2012/10/shelving-uncommitted-changes-in-mercurial/

(see section 'Bug – Added Files Unable Shelve')

Answer (score 0):

If the command line isn't absolutely necessary:

then just type (on Linux)

```
thg shelve
```

This allows you to easily shelve added (but not yet committed) files.

Comment: Since I first thought this was a typo, I thought I'd add a comment that that's Tortoise hg: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TortoiseHg

Comment: @joshua-goldberg this page is now at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TortoiseHg

Answer (score 0):

As a mostly Git user, I find Atlassian [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) the easiest way to deal with the odd Mercurial repo that I have to work with. It has shelving built in. The price is right, too (free).

*Disclaimer: I work for Atlassian*